# For loop not acting as expected

Tags: android

Good night.

I have a `for` loop to calculate some values along the week, during some weeks. My code compare day of the week with the quantity of days that have passed.

The for only works fine on monday when `workday` is the same than `totdays`. The rest of days `totact` is 0 and the fianl equation become `NaN`.

```
            int totdias = PrefProteos.getInt("dia",0);
            int totact = 0;
            float califtot = 0;
            int stateday = 0;
            float promdias;
            float promcalif;
            int workdays;
            Date day = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.US);
            String dayweek = formatter.format(day);
            if (dayweek.equals("Mon")) {
                stateday = 1;
            }
            else if (dayweek.equals("Tue")) {
                stateday = 2;
            }
            else if (dayweek.equals("Wed")) {
                stateday = 3;
            }
            else if (dayweek.equals("Thu")) {
                stateday = 4;
            }
            else if (dayweek.equals("Fri")) {
                stateday = 5;
            }
            else if (dayweek.equals("Sat")) {
                stateday = 6;
            }
            else if (dayweek.equals("Sun")) {
                stateday = 7;
            }

            if (stateday >= totdias) {
                workdays = 1;
                promdias = totdias;
            } else {
                workdays = (totdias - (stateday - 1));
                promdias = stateday;
            }

            for (int y = workdays; y == totdias;y++) {
                for (int x = 1; x <= 12; x++) {
                    String activ=PrefProteos.getString("act" + x + "-habit", "");
                    if (!activ.equals("")) {
                        float notactiv = PrefProteos.getFloat("act" + x + "-puntdia"+y, 0);
                        califtot = califtot+notactiv;
                        totact = totact+1;
                    }
                }
            }

            promcalif = califtot / (totact * promdias);
```

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Comment: `for (int y = workdays; y == totdias;y++) {`, since you ask to use the loop only when `workdays == totdias`, I would guess this might be your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have write your first loop condition wrong, you ask only for to run only if `workdays = totdias`. I guess you want to loop for each days from workdays to totdias
So correct this block :

```
for (int y = workdays; y == totdias;y++) {
```

Into

```
for (int y = workdays; y <= totdias;y++) {
```

PS :

Your current loop is like writing

```
if(workdays == totdias) {
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should provide some more code because we can't understand your `PrefProteos` class and probably the error is in there.
- You should also add the full logcat
- And you should tell us which line throws the error.

**Anyway there are some errors:**

Here

```
for (int y = workdays;y==totdias;y++){
```

There is no sense of using an equals condition in a for loop exit condition if both equals condition and looping variable are the same, because it will result in an if loop. This is because the for will work only if `workdays == totdias` since the beginning, elseway it will not work.

For conditions are:

```
for(counter = defaultvalue; condition that if true, makes the loop goes on; what to do each loop end)
```

This means that your code will do:

```
is y(workdays) == totdias?
  if yes, do the loop
    add one to y(workdays)
    exit because the condition is no more true
  if not, don't run the loop
```

So you simply have to call:

```
if(y == totdias){
  //do code
  y++;
}
```

But probably this is an error, because except for monday, this code will never run! so in others days `promdias` is not istantiated

In the loop

```
for (int x = 1; x<=12; x++){
  String activ=PrefProteos.getString("act" + x + "-habit", "");
  if (!activ.equals("")){
    //there must be an error here somewhere
    float notactiv=PrefProteos.getFloat("act" + x + "-puntdia"+y, 0);
    califtot=califtot+notactiv;
    totact=totact+1;
  }
}
```

And this must be throwing an error.

```
        promcalif = califtot/(totact*promdias);
```

Two options:

- `promidias` or `totact` are `0`. you can't do `number/0`
- As said above, `promdias` might not be istantiated in other days of the week, because the for loop never run

Btw, `float name = 0;` is not perfect, change them to `float name = 0f;`

Comment: You definitly did more review than me ! PS : an `==` could be used in a for loop, but not using the variable declare in the declaration part of course (well even this is not completly true ;) but this is ugly code)

Comment: `if(y == totdias){
  //do code
  y++;
}` is not a loop.  I think he is trying to loop, but his clause is wrong

Comment: @AxelH yeah, probably I missexplained the error, I edit explainng that as he wrote it, is not a loop but an if condition! thanks :)

Comment: @Doomsknight sorry I don't see where I wrote that if(...) is a loop, I said he is doing a loop with an if instead of a loop confition, if you tell me where I will fix it! ;)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Just me skimming for the answer. The next line explains that it is probably not what he wanted to do :)